# Explanation for recursive generator

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this method that solves my binary tree problem where I need to find all children of parent category. It works perfectly but the problem I don't understand how it works so maybe someone can explain it to me step by step because recursions is very hard to understand for some reason.

I have a parent category (categ) and it has child_ids(there can be many more category)
so the question is HOW is `def get_children(categ)`: is working?
P.S. In this function I'm using a bit of my frameworks ORM but I hope it is understandable.

```py
 def onchange_pallet_needed(self, ids, pallet_needed):
        def get_children(categ):
            for child in categ.child_ids:
                yield child
                for grandchild in get_children(child):
                    yield grandchild
        if pallet_needed:
            pallet_needed_list = []
            categ = self.browse(ids[0])
            pallet_needed_list.append(categ.id)
            for child in get_children(categ):
                pallet_needed_list.append(child.id)
            print pallet_needed_list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, `get_children` is a generator.
The `yield` statements pause the execution of the generator to return the specified value. When the next value is requested from the generator, code execution continues from that point.
During the `for` loop, `pallet_needed_list` gets the ids of children appended in the following order (indented for clarity but it would actually all be a single level):

- child1

  - child1's child1

    - child1's child1's child1
    - child1's child1's child2
    - ...
  - child1's child2
  - ...
- child2
- ...

Thus, as another user mentioned, it is a Depth First Search through the tree.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment. I think it is some sort of [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to traverse the tree

which part of it is vague to you?
from the wiki:
The algorithm starts at the root node (selecting some arbitrary node as the root node in the case of a graph) and explores as far as possible along each branch before backtracking.